# Returning a custom command via AjaxResponse

Tags: 8, ajax, redirection

I have a method that is invoked by AJAX call, and it returns an `AjaxResponse`. It redirects the user with `RedirectCommand`, added to the response. However, I would like to change it to a conditional redirect. Is this possible with `RedirectCommand`, or any other way that uses the `CommandInterface`, preferably in a way that does not require implementing `CommandInterface` in a new class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, one way to do this is to implement `CommandInterface` in a new class, [as described in this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210922090329/https://www.mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8). This method adds the new command to `Druapl.AjaxCommands`.

However, if it's not desirable to implement the interface, a similar thing can be done with the existing `InvokeCommand` that implements `CommandInterface`, [as seen in the example here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21InvokeCommand.php/class/InvokeCommand/8.2.x).

My minimalistic example:

Server-side (`NULL` can be some CSS selector instead):

```
$response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'customRedirect', ['/']));
```

Client-side:

```
jQuery.fn.customRedirect = function(target) {
    if (something)
        location.replace(target);
    else
        do_something_else();
};
```